# Fourier transform of Green function using residue theroem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fourier-transform, integration, complex-numbers, greens-functions

I want to compute the Fourier transform of a Green function in $k$-space :

$$
G^R_{n,m}(\omega)=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dk}{2\pi}\frac{e^{ik(n-m)}}{\omega+i\eta-\epsilon_k}
$$

By substituting $\omega$ and using residue theorem I must find the following forms :

$$
G^R_{n,m}(\omega=-2t\cos(\theta))=\frac{e^{i\theta|n-m|}}{2it\sin\theta} \quad\text{for}\quad -2t<\omega<2t
$$

$$
G^R_{n,m}(\omega=2t\cosh(\theta))=\frac{(-1)^{(n-m)}e^{-\theta|n-m|}}{2t\sinh\theta} \quad\text{for}\quad \omega>2t
$$

$$
G^R_{n,m}(\omega=-2t\cosh(\theta))=-\frac{e^{-i\theta|n-m|}}{2t\sinh\theta} \quad\text{for}\quad -2t<\omega<2t
$$

However, I don't really know which contour to integrate over. So can you help me understand how I must compute this Fourier transform ?

Edit :

According to LPZ answer I can change variable $z=e^{ik}$ and since $\epsilon_k=-2t\cos(k)$, with dk=-iz^{-1}dz, Green function now is :

$$
G^R_{n,m}(\omega=-2t\cos\theta)=\oint\frac{dz}{2\pi}\frac{-iz^{(n-m)-1}}{2t((z+z^{-1})/2 - \cos\theta)+i\eta}
$$

By using residue theorem :

$$
G^R_{n,m}(\omega=-2t\cos\theta)=2i\pi Res(f, \cos\theta)
$$

Comment: I wanted to use but since I want to integrate between 0 and 2pi, I don't know how to make it works with Jordan's lemma that is between -inf and +inf.

Comment: My bad, didn't notice the integration bounds. Just do the change of variables $z = e^{ik}$, since $m,n$ are integers, you automatically have a contour integral (unit circle). You'll need the expression of $\epsilon(k)$, and compute its zeros.

Comment: I edited my question following your advice. Do I need to to use complex representation of $\theta$ to conclude ? I understand how I get the exponential in the result but I don't understand how to get the denominator.

Comment: z is the only complex variable in your expression, and it traces out the unit circle in the complex plane; that's your contour. The residue is proportional to the number of poles of your integrand within that unit circle. I would read up on how to calculate the residues of a given complex function.